# Export SPSS data file to Excel showing Value Labels

Tags: excel, export, spss

I would like to export an SPSS.sav file to Excel showing Value Labels instead of values. Is this possible? Thanks, - gg

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in the SAVE AS menu - once you change the file type into Excel you have a checkbox option to "Save value labels where defined instead of data values".

This is how the command would look in syntax (note last line):

```
SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE='C:\Users\user\somefile.xlsx'
  /TYPE=XLS /VERSION=12  /MAP  /REPLACE  /FIELDNAMES
  /CELLS=LABELS.
```

Answer (score 1):

In GNU PSPPIRE there is no given button to SAVE AS xlsx, so I used the syntax.

FILE -> NEW -> SYNTAX -> write the syntax as below -> RUN -> ALL

```
SAVE TRANSLATE /OUTFILE='filename.csv' /TYPE=CSV /MAP /REPLACE /FIELDNAMES /CELLS=LABELS
```

Comment: Note that the resulting file is not an excel file but a CSV file - which can easily be read in Excel.